# Linq to sql query check for equality of tuples

Tags: c#, linq

How write linq to sql query to retrieve records from table below that `(B ,C)` be in list `c`.
Table is in database.

```
var c = new List<(int,int)>{(1,4), (3,6)};

+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| a | 1 | 4 |
| b | 2 | 5 |
| c | 3 | 6 |
+---+---+---+
```

Query should return `a` and `c`.

Comment: Table as in database table? Are you asking about Entity Framework?

Comment: Give an example

Comment: Can you include sample output of  that you need

Comment: Your list does not have `(1,4)` item, it has `(1,3)`, so what is logic of comparison?

Comment: What have you tried so far? please share your code

Comment: Looks more like "not in" than "in" ? From your grid, the `a` (1,4) and `b` (2,5) are not in your list of (1,3) and (3,6)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about tuples being "fully"(all elements are sequentially equal) equal then you can just use contains:

```
var c = new List<(int,int)>{(1,3), (3,6)};
var table = new List<(int,int)>{(1,3), (2,5), (3,6)};
var res = table
   .Where(i => c.Contains(i))
   .ToList();
```

[Equality and tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#equality-and-tuples)

If [@Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard)'s assumption is right then just change `.Where(i => c.Contains(i))` to `.Where(i => !c.Contains(i))`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your logic is but i think you are trying to do something like this,

Let's assume your table model looks like below,

```
public class MyTable {
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    public MyTable(string a, string b, string c) {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }
}
```

And let's fill the data you have shared and query,

```
 var c = new List<(int, int)> { (1, 4), (3, 6) };

 List<MyTable> myTables = new List<MyTable>();
 myTables.Add(new MyTable("a", "1", "4"));
 myTables.Add(new MyTable("b", "2", "5"));
 myTables.Add(new MyTable("c", "3", "6"));

 var res = myTables.Where(x => c.Any(y => y.Item1.ToString() == x.B && y.Item2.ToString() == x.C)).Select(x => x.A);

 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", res));
 Console.ReadKey();
```

**This will print:**

> a c